# Dúvida com cenas (Scene)

Tags: android

Estou começando a utilizar cenas na minha aplicação, e estou tendo constantemente o mesmo problema, mas agora não soube resolver.

Assim, tenho 2 cenas, e no `onCreate` eu pego as minhas views, por exemplo:

```
editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
```

E tudo bem, consigo pegar o texto, pois é como se ele identificasse somente o `EditText` da primeira cena. Mas quando estou na segunda cena, tenho o mesmo item, com o mesmo *Id*, mas quando tento pegar o valor do `EditText` ele pega apenas o valor da primeira cena.

Como posso resolver isso?

**OnCreate da activity:**

```
RelativeLayout baseLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity);

        View startViews = getLayoutInflater()
                .inflate(R.layout.activity_normal, baseLayout, false);

        View endViews = getLayoutInflater()
                .inflate(R.layout.activity_personalized, baseLayout, false);

        scene1 = new Scene(baseLayout, startViews);
        scene2 = new Scene(baseLayout, endViews);

        anticipateTransition = new ChangeBounds();
        anticipateTransition.setDuration(700);
        anticipateTransition.setInterpolator(new AnticipateInterpolator());

        transition = new ChangeBounds();
        transition.setDuration(500);
        transition.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());

        scene1.enter();
        start=true;
```

**layout.activity:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">

</RelativeLayout>
```

**layout.activity_normal:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">
     <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_text"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
</RelativeLayout>
```

**layout.activity_personalized:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">
     <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_text"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Método pra transição**

```
        if (start) {
            TransitionManager.go(scene2, anticipateTransition);
            start = false;
        } else {
            TransitionManager.go(scene1, transition);
            start = true;
        }
```

Comment: Edite a pergunta e coloque a parte relevante do código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem de, após a transição, voltar a usar `findViewById(R.id.edit_text);`

```
if (start) {
    TransitionManager.go(scene2, anticipateTransition);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
    start = false;
} else {
    TransitionManager.go(scene1, transition);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
    start = true;
}
```